# Why are the divs not included in the dark-mode function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to this language. So far I've only dealt with HTML and CSS. That's why I looked up a tutorial. I took the code and tried to change it. It worked for the beginning, but when I tried to add `div`s in dark mode, it didn't work.
So my problem is that the `div`s are not included in the dark mode, and the `font`, `font-color` etc. I thought by adding `div` instead of `body`, it would work. But this was not the case...
I hope you can help me with that.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
toggle.onclick = function() {
  toggle.classList.toggle('active');
  body.classList.toggle('active');
  div.classList.toggle('active')

}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ada9a9 2%, transparent 7%), radial-gradient(#928f8f 2%, transparent 7%);
  background-color: #f8efd6;
  background-position: 25px 35px, 50px 50px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body.active {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#5c5252 2%, transparent 7%), radial-gradient(#928f8f 2%, transparent 7%);
  background-color: #16140f;
  background-position: 25px 35px, 50px 50px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 -4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

#toggle.active {
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 8px 8px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 -4px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#toggle .indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea, #f9f9f9);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 4px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 0 -4px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#toggle.active .indicator {
  left: 60%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #444, #222);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 4px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 -4px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div.active {
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}
```

```html
<div class="power">
  <div id="toggle">
    <i class="indicator"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean that the `divs are not included in dark mode..`? What are you expecting? The snippet appears to work fine.

Comment: I want the background and the font of the boxes to change

Comment: background of the box --> black for example and for the font --> white if it's turned on

Comment: Right now it just changes the background of the whole website

Comment: Well, nowhere in your CSS do you set the color of the font if the div has the `active` class. You could just add `color: white;` to `div.active {}`.

Comment: `const div = document.querySelector('div');` - you are aware that this only selects the first div element in the whole document, yes? And that it won't affect any divs you might be adding dynamically later (if that is what you meant) either? This should not be done by adding classes to a number of elements - but _one_ class to _one_ element, to the body (or html) - and then use the descendant combinator in your stylesheet, to apply formatting to whatever elements might need it. `body.active div { ... }`